# How to navigate User to Specific Cell/Sheet/Page at the time of Document Loading in CSPP WOPI Office Solution?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, ms-wopi, office-web-app

We're trying to implement CSPP WOPI in our App. We're stuck at one point and need your suggestions/support.

Our objective is to open the files in View-Only mode with capability to land a user to specific sheet in the excel.

Let's say there are three sheets in the Excel file and once the file is loaded in the Office Viewer, we want to open the sheet 3rd(using sheet name or index;whatever works) and then move to cell  for example - J105 by highlighting it.

Assuming application has the details of which cell and which sheet to navigate, can we make this possible ?

I read in the documentation that POST Message enables the communication to Office Viewer in iframe but it only supports limited messages/events.

Not sure, how can we enable this custom communication to office Viewer to nagivate the user dyanmically with View-only mode.

Has anyone ever came around or tried to implement something similiar ? Any suggestions on the solution ?